# Lubridate putting dates into the future in R

Tags: r

When I do this code:

```
library(lubridate)
df$date <- format(as.Date(df$date, "%m/%d/%y") , "%Y")
```

Some of the dates that are meant to be in the 1900s, eg: 1960, turn to 2060. I'm not sure how to fix this. The date range I want is 1951 - 2014, and I have around 8000 observations.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example from your data that produces this error? We don't have access to the contents of `df$date`, which makes it difficult to help.

Comment: 8/20/68 turns to 2068, and this happens for all dates from 1951-1968

Comment: But 1999 - 1969 work fine ... I don't know what's making this cut off decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have 2-digit years. From `?strptime`

> Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.

So all 2 digit years from 00-68 are prefixed with 20, hence 60 turns to 2060 and not 1960.

There could be various ways to handle this. One way would be to subtract 100 years from dates whose year is more than 2014 (since we know the range of years).

For example,

```
df <- data.frame(date = c('1/12/60', '1/12/78' ,'1/1/91', '1/1/54'))
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%m/%d/%y")
df
#        date
#1 2060-01-12
#2 1978-01-12
#3 1991-01-01
#4 2054-01-01

inds <- as.numeric(format(df$date, "%Y")) > 2014
df$date[inds] <- df$date[inds] - lubridate::years(100)
df
#        date
#1 1960-01-12
#2 1978-01-12
#3 1991-01-01
#4 1954-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with `chron` as the cut-off date is 1961 by default

```
as.Date(chron::dates(c('01/12/60', '01/12/78' ,'01/01/91', '01/01/54')))
#[1] "1960-01-12" "1978-01-12" "1991-01-01" "1954-01-01"
```